# What consumes less, to use ArrayList or System.arraycopy

Tags: java, arraylist, arrays

Maybe obvious but I want to know what and **why** is the best practice when keeping down the consumption of system resources.

When I want to dynamically expand an Array I can use either

```
System.arraycopy(arraystuff, 0, tempArray, 0, arraystuff.length);
```

or

```
ArrayList
```

Easiest is of course `ArrayList` but is there any reason to use `arraycopy` ?

Comment: Good practice would be to use a `List` implementation; whether this be `ArrayList`, another list from `java.util` or a custom implementation. Performance should be secondary.

Comment: What do you think `ArrayList` uses internally?

Comment: Hi, nice question, but I think you should to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Over there you will probably find better experts (if you will do, then you should to delete this question there to avoid cross domain posting)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx no, because there is no working code to review.

Comment: @AndyTurner k then, thanks for clarify, but I think there is no general answer, it will depend on frequency of expanding, as well about amount of expanding, etc. not?

Comment: Thanks you all guys for your effort to clerify thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost always, you should use the higher-level abstraction. You often don't need to care that `ArrayList` resizes itself internally, or even that it stores the data in an array (most of the time, you'll have a `List` reference, not an `ArrayList`); it "just works".

However, the resizing strategy is fixed with `ArrayList`: it always resizes by [a multiplicative factor of 1.5](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#255) in order to amortize the cost of reallocating the array over many additions. This could lead to wasting a lot of space if, say, you only needed to add 1 more element to a full 1,000,000 element list.

True, you can use [`trimToSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize--) to get rid of this wasted space, but only after the fact: you'd then be allocating a 1.5M-element array *and* a (1M+1)-element array. The 1.5M-element array would only be allocated transiently, and could then be GC'd, but that's still more effort than just allocating the (1M+1)-element array directly.

In that case, you might want to have something that you have more control over how it resizes, and in that situation, using `System.arraycopy` might be more appropriate.

But really, until you have profiled your code and found that `ArrayList` is using too much space, just stick with that.

---

Note also that you might find [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) easier to work with than `System.arraycopy` for the purposes of resizing an array, because it takes fewer parameters and is type-safe. (It uses `System.arraycopy` internally).

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy()` is a native method while `ArrayList` is a high-level Java implementation, which will eventually call `System.arraycopy()`. Therefore, in terms of performance, `System.arraycopy()` is definitely better. But in general, unless *every bit* of performance matters for your application, it is generally more favorable to use a `List`.

Comment: Thanks @Jai for your short correct answer but I find Andys answer a bit more informativ.